# PySerial communication from Ard. to RPi 3

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial, serial-communication

I'm trying to send a string of data from the Arduino to the RPi and then try to separate the string with `var1, var2, var3, var4 = dataard.split(",")`

The Arduino is sending me a constant stream of variables in a format like this `!var1,var2,var3,var4?!var1,var2,var3,var4?!var1`
but I only want to select the variables the way I posted above. How do I do it?
How do I time when the RPi reads what is coming in from the Serial port?

This is the way I read the serial data.

```
ard = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=9600)
startflag = " "
while startflag != "":
          dataard = ard.readline()
          startflag = " "
```

but sometimes I receive the string like this `var2,var3,var4var1` or `var4var1,var2,var3`

How do I fix it? What do I have to do that I will always receive the variables in this format `var1,var2,var3,var4`

EDIT:

I found that I get inconsistent values as well, when I tried to do `dataard = ard.readline(35)`. I sometimes get `!var1,var2,var3` or `var2,var3,var4?` and `var4!var1,var2,var3`

Comment: If you make the Arduino put a different separator at the end of each line, for example \n, in the Pi you can decode between \n characters and know you are looking at a complete set of variables separated by , (comma) - this scheme also allows you to add further variables and it still works. Effectively what you are doing is adding some framing into your protocol.

Comment: @barny that's what I was thinking about. Do you have any idea how to do that code-wise? I'm not really sure and didn't really find anything besides python parition, which I don't know how to implement that it fits my needs tbh.

Comment: What you need to do is a) always look for data from a receive buffer - look for the end of frame character, if it isn't there then b) read everything more there is from the serial port and add to the end of the receive buffer, or if it is there then c) remove just that frame from the receive buffer and process it. Then after either b or c go back to a. The reason you need to use the buffer is that you may not have received a complete frame - and when you do get the end of frame you may also have received the first few characters of the next frame so those need to be kept in the buffer.